# How do i configure install4j to point to user dir

Tags: install4j

Am using install4j to create a Mac build. My folder structure is:

- App Folder

  - images
  - jar file

Post installation when i run the application images dont load. In the program reference to the image folder is "/images/imagename.jpg".

How do i fix this